# Meaning of the command

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have used the following very simple command to draw ellipse-type partial curves. But, I didn't get the meaning of the parameters used there. The command is

> \draw (4,0) arc (0:180:4 and 1);

Can you help me to get meaning of the parameters and how this command works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The long form with descriptive option names is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % \draw (4, 0) arc (0:180:4 and 1);
    \draw
      (xyz cs:x=4, y=0) % shorter: (xyz cs:x=4)
      arc[
        start angle=0,
        end angle=180,
        x radius=4,
        y radius=1,
      ]
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For details, see the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) of pgf/TikZ.
The syntax for the coordinate system `xyz` is explained in section "13.2.1 Canvas, XYZ, Polar Coordinate Systems", subsection "Coordinate system xyz". The short form of the `arc` syntax is explained in "14.7 The Arc Operation".